# Getting LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials . nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException during login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, opendj

Getting [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials] error[image: Find the error screen shot here].
When I try to login from spring security.
I have tried this service with OpenDJ 3.0 as well as 4.4.7 version.
LDAP server is running on port 1389.Below is my LDAP configuration code.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0}, ou=People")
       // .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=People")

        //.groupSearchBase("ou=groups,ou=users")
         // .groupSearchBase("ou=People")
        //.userSearchFilter("(cn={0})")
        .contextSource()
       //.setUserDn("cn=john,ou=Users,dc=testathon,dc=net")
       //.url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
           .url("ldap://worker01:1389/dc=example,dc=com")
            .managerDn("cn=Directory Manager,dc=example,dc=com")
            .managerPassword("Password123") 
           // System.out.println("hi");
            //.managerPassword("{SSHA512}0B6MVegtPTE6DcK0pqzMfDRnC0CwRCrCliJD0txyYaNCb0tKR6B1m+Jpp+7R5pNS1cAVuj2Ff0ao0pKxjsoGP5JaGPxqzyIR")
          .and()
          .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }

}
```

I am able to login on OenDJ server from control panel from same credential and its working fine, I can add new entry, update password and delete it, but when I try to login from spring boot application I am getting invalid credential error. I have also update Directory manager password from command prompt and its updated successfully.

I am unable to find the solution.
Below is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>ldap-springboot-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ldap-springboot-service</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- <version>3.0.0-M5</version> -->
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Check the OpenDJ access log file, and there should be a more detailed reason for the failure with the Bind result that fails with error 49.

Comment: Below are my logs

Comment: Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3259) ~[na:na]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3205) ~[na:na]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2991) ~[na:na]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2905) ~[na:na]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:348) ~[na:na]
 at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapC
 ... 60 common frames omitted

Comment: When I export LDIF file userpassword is prefixed with {BCRYPT } or {SSHA} I have changed the password storage scheme to Bcrypt. I am able through ldif file if I remove {BCRYPT} from userpassword.

Comment: dn: uid=deepak,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
sn: Patel
cn: deepak
givenName: Deepak
userPassword: $2a$12$9XQ6V1ytYU//F7qSNOpAW.uD.q7FEqLO35NvrzEFCLN71CRqDVSzG
uid: deepak
createTimestamp: 20201118063555Z
creatorsName: cn=Directory Manager,cn=Root DNs,cn=config
entryUUID: da5a65f6-775b-420a-91bd-07dd6f136c6b

Comment: i think it might be this: .managerDn("cn=Directory Manager,dc=example,dc=com"), you dont need to specify the full path for dirManager, and anyway its never placed in the baseDn, so update it to .managerDn("cn=Directory Manager"),

Comment: The logs above are not from OpenDJ, but the client side logs. It also seems to me that the code is trying to read the user entry and "userPassword" attribute and compare the values. This is not a DS authentication. This is local comparison. Which is very dependent on identical implementations of the hashing algorithms on both sides.